# Using Teamcity parameter can we override the variable value in MS tests app configuration file?

Tags: teamcity, mstest

I am using Ms test unit framework, transformed the config file using cheetah. While running it from TeamCity I need to replace the variable value in the config file using the TeamCity parameter. Do we have a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

File content replacer build feature might help you.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/2020.1/file-content-replacer.html#Specifying+path+patterns+which+contain+spaces

You add it as a build feature :

[image]